# parsing badly formed xml in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing

I have been using the xml library in visual studio 2010 to parse xml data and it works well unless we come across a post that is missing a tag or even just a space somewhere causes an error. To handle the error xml posts I use regular expressions to parse and yes I have been warned about this and never heeded the warnings simply because it was easier to implement. Now having had this in production for a while parsing errors were detected and this is now a big mess.

What are better alternatives to handling bad xml? I know I could clean up the xml and check for opening and closing tags but what about other sort of errors that crop up. I want to know if there is a tool compatible with visual studio to work around this and be more accurate than regular expressions?
I saw a library called Beautiful Soup for python that handles bad xml apparently.
Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 is not a programming language.  Do you mean .Net?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: will this only fix the bad xml or can I still grab the tags that are in the xml

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying.